# Could someone help me with approaches for marketing expenditure allocation

Tags: time-series, optimization, model, marketing

I have to assign marketing budget to different marketing programs across regions for the next fiscal year. For this, I want to assign weightages to different parameters that might affect the outcome of spending. The data I have is as follows:
- last 2 years outcome of some (not all) marketing programs (at program level, not available at customer level). Also historically, there is high variance in outcome of programs (for whom data is available) from one period to another.
- last 3 years overall revenues and market share
- share of wallet of purchasers
- stage in life cycle of purchasers (new, existing, etc.)
- last 3 years market size and projected FY18 market size

How do I use all this data to come up with marketing spending allocation?
Coming up with subjective numbers based on intuition/experience is not an option.
I know different businesses use different approaches for marketing allocation, but I want some concrete approach best suited for this case.